# Does putting warm things in a freezer/fridge actually cost that much more?

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, temperature, everyday-life, estimation

I am going to use fridge/freezer interchangeably within this question.

When I put warm food in the fridge, the heat will get moved from the food to the kitchen obviously. Any inefficiency caused by the heat pump will also get dumped into the kitchen as heat. Since I paid money to heat up the food using my oven it would be throwing that money out of the window when I put the food outside for it to cool down first, correct?

Also how could I calculate how much energy is saved in my heater for the kitchen, when the heat just radiates away from the food or comes out of the fridge?

In other words; Isn't it negligeable if the food cools on the counter or in the fridge if I need to heat my room in the winter anyways?

Comment: The reason of not putting hot food in the fridge is so as not to raise the temperature of the food already cooled to 5 c  (or -18c in the freezer). It destroys the quality of food to change temperature while in the fridge. So we are careful to let hot food cool to room temperature to avoid too large a shock to the existing food in the fridge..

Answer (score 1):

From a strict undergraduate physics, "all cows are spherical" point of view, no it shouldn't make a difference.

This ignores:

- Whether it'll be nice and warm behind the fridge and freezing everywhere else.
- The impact on food safety of leaving stuff sitting warm on the counter.
- The fact that in *summer* if you're trying to *cool* the house it'll cost you twice.
- Wear and tear on the fridge (fridge compressors are mechanical devices and subject to wear).
- Whatever I forgot.

Comment: If its warmer behind the fridge that warmth will still have to spread out, the only way you'd be inefficient is if more of that heat flowed out of the house through the walls than if it was supplied instead by the heater.

Comment: It's certainly not efficient in a "gee I'm glad I'm not freezing" sense.  But yes -- assuming that the fridge location doesn't foster more heat leaking out of the house, in theory it wouldn't make a difference.